# How to extract Route Params via Props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli-3

I am learning VueJs and trying to understand how to extract `route` `params` via `props`.

I was looking at the following documentation, where it seems to have three options to have this done, but I cannot understand it quite well so far - `https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/tree/dev/examples/route-props`.

I have tried adding `props: true` to my `router` object array (routes.js file posted below) with no success as well.

As this is `vue-cli` study project I will post the separate pertinent blocks of code in order to try to illustrate this properly.

**Main - App.vue below:**

```
 <template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>Routing</h1>
                <hr>
                <app-header></app-header>
                <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Header from './components/Header.vue'
    export default {
        components: {
            appHeader: Header
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**Component - Header.vue below:**

```
<template>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <router-link to="/" tag="li" active-class="active" exact><a>Home</a></router-link>
        <router-link to="/user/10" tag="li" active-class="active"><a>User 1</a></router-link>
        <router-link to="/user/5" tag="li" active-class="active"><a>User 2</a></router-link>

    </ul>
</template>
```

**Component - User.vue below:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>The User Page</h1>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <p>Route ID: {{id}}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="goHome">Go to Home</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                id: this.$route.params.id
            }
        },
        watch: {
          '$route'(to, from) {
              this.id = to.params.id;
          }
        },
        methods: {
            goHome(){
                this.$router.push('/')
            }
        }

    }

</script>
```

**main.js below:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import {routes} from "./routes";

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**routes.js below (located at SRC folder):**

```
import User from './components/user/User.vue'
import Home from './components/Home.vue'

export const routes = [
    {path: '', component: Home},
    {path: '/user/:id', component: User}
]
```

Do I need to also set `Props` at `User.vue` component as well in order to make it work and quit using `watch`?

In other words, I would like to see my user route being listened at `<p>Route ID: {{id}}</p>` from this hardcoded `10` to `5` using this new method which I cannot understand, mentioned at the top of this post.

Could anyone please walk me through this issue in this specific situation?

Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs on [passing Props to Route components](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components), you can decouple it, with the `props` option on the router config.

```js
import User from './components/user/User.vue'
import Home from './components/Home.vue'

export const routes = [
    {path: '', component: Home},
    {path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: true}
]
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>The User Page</h1>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <p>Route ID: {{id}}</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="goHome">Go to Home</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['id'],

    methods: {
      goHome() {
        this.$router.push('/')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! So in fact there was a need to set props @ ```User.vue``` file! It works and its pretty neat. Thanks dear Yom